# Declare a fixed-length variable equal to '' ( empty string )

Tags: sql-server, string, variables

Is it possible to declare a fixed length string variable with a length of 0? Use case is for dynamic SQL generation. I've got a couple gimmes right away with

```
declare 
    @SqlQuery nvarchar( max ) = '',
    @lb nchar( 1 ) = char( 10 ),
    @tab nchar( 1 ) = char( 9 ),
    @sq nchar( 1 ) = char( 39 ), -- single quote
    @dq nchar( 2 ) = char( 39 ) + char( 39 ) -- 2x single quote
```

For readability lower in the proc, I'd like to include an "Empty String" variable `@es` for `isnull( Column, @es )` cleanup so I don't break my concatenation on the `null` value. However, I'm not having much success achieving this. Attempts below. Any insight?

```
go
declare @EmptyString char( 0 ) = '' ;
print 'empty string [' + @EmptyString + ']';
--Msg 1001, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
--Line 1: Length or precision specification 0 is invalid.
go
declare @EmptyString char( 1 ) = '' ; 
print len( @EmptyString ); --0
print '[' + replicate( @EmptyString, 10 ) + ']'; --[          ]
go
```

Comment: Why was this question migrated to S.O.? That makes no sense? (this question is not for Peter, btw).

Comment: @srutzky it was flagged as off topic by the mods. I assume it was seen as not up to par for dba.SE questions. While I may not agree, I requested the migration to SO as a more general question rather than live with the flag

Comment: Yeah, but it wasn't off topic, and it already had 2 (last time I checked) re-open votes (1 of them mine). I don't recall the exact text of the "off topic" reason, but this just seems silly.

Comment: Haha, apologies for requesting the migration, then. I don't really give a fig where the question lives, just happy to have an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't know that you requested it. This is fine, then. I think they were silly to have flagged it as "off topic". I had figured it was a response to the miscommunication / disconnect in the beginning about char(0)/etc. No need to apologize. Here is fine, as long as you are not unhappy with the location. But I still don't agree with it having been closed in the first place (which is nothing on you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot declare a string variable or field with a max length of 0 (at least not in SQL Server). Given that limitation, a fixed-length datatype of `CHAR` / `NCHAR` cannot, by definition, contain an empty string since the min length is 1 and will always be blank-padded.

The reason that `len( @EmptyString )` shows as `0` is because trailing spaces are removed for comparisons. If you were to also try `print datalength( @EmptyString );` you would see that it returns `1`, which accounts for the space. And if you were to change the `declare @EmptyString char( 1 )` to be `NCHAR(1)`, then the `DATALENGTH(@EmptyString)` would return `2` even though the `LEN` function would still return 0.

The reason that `'[' + replicate( @EmptyString, 10 ) + ']'` produced `[          ]` is because a `CHAR(1)`, being blank-padded, is not actually empty, even if set to just `''`, so that statement really replicated a space character 10 times.

The only way to get an empty string is to use `NVARCHAR(x) = N''`. While `x` can technically be a value from 1 - 4000 or even `MAX`, for this purpose it should probably just be `1`. The variable nature of `NVARCHAR` / `VARCHAR` will give you an empty string, even if declared as `NVARCHAR(100)`.

The following shows that this indeed works:

```sql
DECLARE @EmptyString NVARCHAR( 10 ) = N''; 
PRINT LEN( @EmptyString ); -- 0
PRINT DATALENGTH( @EmptyString ); -- 0
PRINT '[' + REPLICATE( @EmptyString, 10 ) + ']'; -- []
```